# Row Count for GridView with paging

Tags: asp.net, gridview

So I have user controls with GridView tables. I have more tables that are much bigger than this one and have paging enabled, but I'm using this as an example. I want each table to display like this one, where a table with a hundred rows will say "Showing: 1 - 10 of 100" on the first page, "Showing: 11 - 20 of 100" on the second, etc.

[image]
This is how it is coded now (in my html file):

```
<div id="WebsiteHitsMacro">
     <umbraco:Macro ID="Macro303" Alias="WebsiteHitsControl" runat="server"></umbraco:Macro>
</div>
<div class="ui-widget-header ui-state-default ui-corner-bl ui-corner-br ui-helper clearfix bottom">
    <div class="dataTables_info" id="websitehits_info">Showing: 1-6 of 6</div>
</div>
```

Here's the ascx code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
   DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" CssClass="dataTable" AllowPaging="True" 
   AllowSorting="True">
   <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="altrow" />
   <HeaderStyle CssClass="ui-state-default" />
   <Columns>
   <asp:BoundField DataField="id" HeaderText="id" SortExpression="id" />
   <asp:BoundField DataField="name" HeaderText="name" SortExpression="name" />
   </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

I don't know how to get the row count in the first place. Is it possible to have it display in the div I have here?

I hope this makes sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the total amount of rows across all pages of the grid, then use the `GridView.Rows`, because it represents a collection of all the data rows in your grid. You can use the `Count` property of that collection, like this:

C#:

```
int totalRowsCount = GridView1.Rows.Count;
```

VB.NET:

```
Dim totalRowsCount As Integer = GridView1.Rows.Count
```

Now, your problem is that, from what I can see of your posted code, your user control does not expose this information via properties or events that the page can use. I recommend putting this `Showing 1-6 of 6` message into the user control itself, so it has component level access to the grid and can easily get the information it needs to display. Either a footer row in the grid or a label that sits right below the actual grid itself.

Comment: The question refers to a GridView with paging, while this answer does not work with paging enabled (it gets the number of currently displayed rows).

Answer (score 3):

You said that your `Gridview` has a paging. By using `Dim cnt As Integer = Gridview1.Rows.Count`, it only returns the number of rows in Gridview and not the total number of rows the datasource has filtered.

Since you are using SqlDataSource, try this code:

```
Protected Sub SqlDataSource1_Selected(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSourceStatusEvent Args) Handles
SqlDataSource1.Selected

  Dim cnt As Integer = e.AffectedRows

End Sub
```